# Make a video recorded not using already existing app

Tags: android, record, video-capture

I created an app that records video using the external camera app. I was told there is a way to have your app record video by just calling the camera. I have been stuck for a few days seeing if anyone wanted to lend a hand. Here is my code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class ActivityRecord extends Activity{
    private MediaRecorder recorder;
    private String OUTPUT_FILE;


    private Uri fileUri;
    //public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;
    static final int REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE = 1;
    private static final int CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
    public static ActivityRecord ActivityContext =null; 
    public static TextView output;
    Intent takeVideoIntent;


    public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_record);

        ActivityContext = this;

        Button buttonRecording = (Button)findViewById(R.id.recordButton);
       // output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);

        buttonRecording.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // create new Intentwith with Standard Intent action that can be
                // sent to have the camera application capture an video and return it. 
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                }

                // create a file to save the video
                fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE); 

                // set the image file name  
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);  

                // set the video image quality to high
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1); 

                // start the Video Capture Intent
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

            }});


    }


        // Check that the SDCard is mounted
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                  Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraVideo");
       public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
        public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO1 = 2;

        /** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
        private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
              return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
        }

        /** Create a File for saving an image or video */
        private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
            // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
            // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

            File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                      Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
            // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
            // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

            // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
            if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
                if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                    Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                    return null;
                }
            }

            // Create a media file name
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("20140129_HHmmss").format(new Date(type));
            File mediaFile;
            if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
                mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
            } else if(type == REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE) {
                mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
            } else {
                return null;
            }

            return mediaFile;
        }
}
```

I want to record video from iside the app not using the camera app given with the phone. Below are my errors.

[image]

Comment: What problem are you having/what errors are you seeing/what is your question?

Comment: So what is your question? What error(s) do you get?

Comment: My quedtion is how to call and use the camera without using the built in camera app

Answer (score 0):

In your `buttonRecording` `onClick(...)` method you create an `Intent` called `intent` but then you try to use `takeVideoIntent` which you declared in your `Activity` but never initialised. That's why you get a `NullPointerException`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
}
```